# Dash: Keep Tabs bar on top and remember where was scrolled between tabs

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have two things I want to accomplish in below example of Dash application.

1. Keep the Tabs bar "frozen" on the top of application, so If someone scrolled down to e.g. 500 row can easily select other tab without scrolling "up"
2. If 1 achieved. "Remember" at which Row user scrolled down so when changing between tabs it's still on the same Row of application.

Simplified app:

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_html_components as html

# App
app = dash.Dash(__name__,
                external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.FLATLY],
                title='TestCards')
server = app.server


# Layout
text = [[f'Row_{i}', html.Br()] for i in range(1000)]
text = [item for sublist in text for item in sublist]

tab1_content = html.Div([html.H1(f'Title Tab1'),
                         html.P(text)])

tab1 = dbc.Card(dbc.CardBody([tab1_content]))

tab2_content = html.Div([html.H1(f'Title Tab2'),
                         html.P(text)])

tab2 = dbc.Card(dbc.CardBody([tab2_content]))

app.layout = html.Div([dbc.Tabs(
    [dbc.Tab(tab1, label='Tab1'),
     dbc.Tab(tab2, label='Tab2')])])

# Run App
app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

What it looks like when loaded and scrolled down:
[image]

What I would like to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an id to your Tabs component, for example:

```py
dbc.Tabs(
    [dbc.Tab(tab1, label='Tab1'),
     dbc.Tab(tab2, label='Tab2')], id="my-tabs")
```

Then add this css in your app:

```css
#my-tabs {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate based on above example where and how to add that css? I'v never did before.

Comment: Adding custom css to you dash app is actually pretty simple, have a look at this: https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources

Comment: 1st Task is Done. Thanks! Can you help with 2nd? So the slider should be independent from tabs. So If I scroll down to row 50 on Tab1 and change to Tab2 and scroll down to 200 and then If I go back to Tab1 I want to be on row 50.